# What kind of java eclipse projects run on server

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, junit

I wish to ask what kind of java eclipse projects can be run on server. What are the properties that define that it can be run on server as this option is not shown in all projects in eclipse. Some projects run on just Junit if a test case is built. I am a dummy to programming and would be grateful if somebody explains it in layman's terms

Answer (score 1):

Ok, in layman terms:

The java projects which are to be deployed on a server (which need either a web server or an Application server with container) will show the "Run on Server" option. Like any web Application or an enterprise application (EJB/Webservice etc.) which needs a container for deployment.

The stand-alone projects, generally with a *main* class, can be run directly from your IDE, without the need for deployment on any server.

There is lot of information available on the internet, you can do some research and get some expert understanding once you are clear with this *layman* understanding.

Happy learning! :)